# Spring boot @Autowired null initialization

Tags: java, spring, jpa, groovy, spring-security

Can anyone help me? I'm trying to configure Spring Security with Spring Data JPA. I use Spring Boot and want to fill the DB in CommandLineRunner.run(), so I need to import my repositories, also I need those repositories in the UserDetailsService implementation. In both I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository interface must not be null on initialization!
```

Application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource('classpath:application.properties')
class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
Environment environment

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository

@Autowired
UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository

static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run DemoApplication, args
}

@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    def source = new DriverManagerDataSource(
            environment.getProperty("jdbc.host"),
            environment.getProperty("jdbc.login"),
            environment.getProperty("jdbc.password")
    )
    source.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driver"))
    return source
}



@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    def user = new User(
            username: 'user',
            password: 'user'
    )
    def admin = new User(
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
    )

    userRoleRepository.deleteAll()
    userRepository.deleteAll()


    userRepository.save(user)
    userRepository.save(admin)

    userRoleRepository.save(
            new UserRole(
                    user: user,
                    role: 'ROLE_USER'
            )
    )
    userRoleRepository.save(
            new UserRole(
                    user: admin,
                    role: 'ROLE_USER'
            )
    )
    userRoleRepository.save(
            new UserRole(
                    user: admin,
                    role: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
            )
    )


}



}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl code:

```
@Service('userDetailsService')
class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository

@Override
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    def user = userRepository.findOne(username)

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.username,
            user.password,
            buildUserAuthority(user.userRole)

    )
}


Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing a [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation over `DemoApplication`. Is `UserRepository` in the same package or subpackage as the `DemoApplication` class?

Comment: @orid [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)  annotation has alredy exist in [@SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html). DemoApplication class is in root project, so UserRepository is in subpackage. The exception apear only when i autowire repository in both classes, if i autowire in one of them, it is fine

Answer (score 0):

@Autowired,when you autowire the same var,once is ok,you are right.
example:

```
@Service("notifyRegService")
public class NotifyRegServiceImpl implements INotifyRegService {

@Autowired
private NotifyConfigProperties notifyConfigProperties;
@Autowired
NotifyRepository notifyRepository;
@Service("notifyOffService")
public class NotifyOffServiceImpl implements INotifyOffService {

@Autowired
private NotifyConfigProperties notifyConfigProperties;
// @Autowired
NotifyRepository notifyRepository;
```

like this,everything is ok.